# What is the difference between git diff and git diff HEAD?

Tags: git

I stumbled while reading the following at atlassian :
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-diff

```
git diff HEAD ./path/to/file
```

> This example is scoped to ./path/to/file when invoked, it will compare
>   the specific changes in the working directory, against the index,
>   showing the changes that are not staged yet. By default git diff will
>   execute the comparison against HEAD. Omitting HEAD in the example
>   above git diff ./path/to/file has the same effect.

I figured out that there are cases they will not be the same , if the file I have is staged then no changes for git diff. but for git diff HEAD it will compare with the head instead of index. so is the sentence below wrong ?

> By default git diff will execute the comparison against HEAD

because it compares with the index

Comment: Maybe the documentation is assuming that the default, in that particular example, would have an empty stage, so specifying `HEAD` would be optional.  But, in your example, omitting `HEAD` wouldn't mean the same thing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but it's wrong, I can see different results. so I'm understanding it right, correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's my take.  The documentation is perhaps worded in a confusing way.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you can answer the question and I will approve it. Thanks

Comment: In my experience, many on line Git tutorials, including some of the Atlassian ones, are not very good. Git's own documentation is usually correct but is not very *tutorial*, so there's a problem here: the tutorials are easy to read and wrong, and the Git documentation is correct but difficult to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My read of your question is that the example given in the documentation is assuming that the stage is empty, and, in particular, no version of the file in question has been staged versus what is in the working directory.

Under these assumptions, the `HEAD` option which appears after `git diff` would be unnecessary, because in this case omitting `HEAD` would result in the stage being used.  And both of these should be the same, so `HEAD` therefore becomes optional, at least in this example.